# I enable my hrt using the nucleof334r8 card. What is Burst Mode, how to calibrate?

Tags: stm32

I activated the hrtim timer on the Nucleof334-r8 board. I want to learn what burst mode is and how to use its parameters in high resolution timer which has many parameters. Can you give me information about this?

I don't have anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m1gC.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Reference manual for your MCU is where all information about every peripheral is. How it works, how to use.

Comment: I have attached an image regarding the configuration settings. The processor used is the stm32f334r8t6 processor from the stm family.

Comment: As @Ilya said above, everything is described in the Reference Manual (RM). Burst mode in particular is described in the _Burst mode controller_ subchapter of _HRTIM_ chapter in RM. Calibration is described in _HRTIM initialization_ subchapter.